# Python: text overlay on top of all windows including fullscreen in Linux

Tags: python, linux, x11, framebuffer

I am trying to write a simple script in python that outputs text on top of all windows and fullscreen apps.

The purpose of this script is to output load average and free memory (and other useful stats) in similar fashion that Steam FPS counter works.

So far I tried pygame but as far as I can see it can only write into its own window.

As I understand I need to write directly to frame buffer?

The target OS is Linux with Nvidia card and Xorg, but I would prefer it to be hardware agnostic.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot write to the frame buffer. X11 is a network protocol, there's no frame buffer you can access. You may have to use low-level x11 APIs though. It won't be simple.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to do the same, and so far it worked - but I'm not sure about fullscreen apps - with PyOsd:
http://python-osd.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.2.14-5.1/index.html

Simplest example is

```
import pyosd
p=pyosd.osd()
p.display("Hello world!")
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. The lib is a bit clunky but does the job. It even works in 3D full screen applications!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it helped, and sorry for not having used the codebox.

Are you also trying to get the OSD to update at 20/30 frames per second (or more)?

Comment: It would be nice, but once in a few seconds update is fast enough to get gist of things, specifically to figure out where is the bottle neck.