# Python text overlay on top of everything else

Tags: python, overlay

I'm trying to display the result of a neural net reading picture input from the screen to show what it guesses in the corner. So like I'll have a slide show of cat and dog pictures running in the background and my python code takes a screenshot every couple seconds and feeds to the neural net and gets an answer whether it's a cat or dog. I wanna show "cat"/"dog" in the corner of the screen, on top of video and everything else going on.

I found someone already asked this couple years back

[Python: text overlay on top of all windows including fullscreen in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998489/python-text-overlay-on-top-of-all-windows-including-fullscreen-in-linux#)

but the module the answer suggested(pyosd) doesn't exist anymore apparently. Tring to:

```
pip install pyosd
```

returns

```
"no matching distribution found for pyosd"
```

Comment: If you are looking for a library or framework of code to use, then please ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/dzen/pyosd) link and see if it solves your problem

Comment: I honestly don't even know if I need a whole library or there are existing things I can use. The answer in the post I referenced in my question was only 3 lines of code, but that doesn't seem valid anymore. So I was hoping someone could give me a valid alternative

Comment: ThatBird: I went down the rabbit hole with that link and got something to download, but it seems to all be linux files. None of the commands that the instructions give me to use run on windows command prompt

Comment: Go for PyQt5. It's pretty quick and easy to get something up and working. I made an overlay for my games that shows my heart rate, it displays over all full screen windows. I copied the relevant bits here https://hastebin.com/ahayupaxaz.py

Comment: @Different55 could you include the relevant imports at the top of your hastebin snippet?  Having some trouble getting it to run, but I'm interested in your recommendation.

Comment: PyQt5 imports are `from PyQt5.QtCore import *; from PyQt5.QtGui import *; from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit old, but hopefully this might help someone out.

If you're using OpenCV2 for image processing. You might consider using OpenCV2's putText function to overlay text on the image.

```
import cv2 as cv

# Read image from file path or from a video or screenshot feed
img = cv.imread(targetImgPathOrScreenshotFeed, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Your detection method here to return either cat or dog result

# Overlay text on this image 
# cv.putText(img, text, distanceFromOrgin(Top left), fontFace, fontScale, colour, thickness)
cv.putText(img, 'Dog', (30, 70), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, (255, 255, 255), 1)

# Display result if necessary
cv.imshow('Detection Result', img)
```